# Is there a way to create Google Gsuite account ID using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api

Is there a way to create Google Gsuite account ID using Google API in ASP.NET C#

Answer (score 1):

Almost all GSuite operations are available through Web APIs, which means you can make the proper calls directly, eg using HttpClient. The API you need in this case is the [Directory API in the Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/). The SDK explains how to use the API to [manage users](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users), including [creating new users](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#create_user)

Google also provides client libraries for multiple languages, including [.NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/). The [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/admin/directory_v1) is supported

You'll have to start with the [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started) guide to learn how to connect to Google in the first place and send requests to various APIs. The pattern is similar for all APIs - you create a `XYZService` instance for the API you want. Resources and operations appear as properties and methods under the Service class.

Comment: thanks for reply Panagiotis
i have done already google OAuth, API key, project etc
rest of step i try

Comment: I have done with this link https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/insert

Can u please provide me some code related to this

Comment: (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/insert)
above link, i have done all steps
but i need C# code not jquery/javascript 
Can u please provide me some code related to this